# How to convert string to base64 in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for a way to convert a string to Base64 in react native such as btoa().

btoa() is only working when developer tools are open.

Thanks,
Eranbo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above I ended up writing my self base64 encoder decoder.
I've uploaded it to npm and you are all welcome to use it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-base64
Enjoy,
eranbo

Answer (score 3):

> btoa() is only working when developer tools are open

It`s because in debug mode and without it code work in different js engines (V8 and coreJS). I guess (if it really did not work), the coreJS has not `btoa` implementation.

Use third party libs for it. For example [npm:js-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64).

Comment: Thanks @kirill I ended up writing my own encode decode service class.

Comment: Maybe I'll upload it to npm

Answer (score 0):

rn-fetch-blob allow you to do the conversion in native code :

```
export const blobToBase64 = async (data, encoding = 'base64') => fs.readFile(data, encoding);
```

Comment: Yeah, but my package is much simpler with no need to run link command on the react native cli and the most important stuff it's small, one file, easy to understand change and use

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in vanilla js like follow :

```
export const UriToBase64 = blob => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (window.FileReader) {
      const reader = new window.FileReader();
      if (blob && blob.type.match('image.*')) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onerror = reject;
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Bad type, must be image'));
      }
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    } else {
      reject(new Error('No FileReader on window'));
    }
  });
};

export default {
  UriToBase64,
};
```

Comment: Hi Alex Levy,
in React-Native there is no window

Comment: Sorry it's because I use React Native Web